# What is the best way to implement generic Repository pattern based on JSON.NET and returning IQueryable<T>?

Tags: c#, json, linq, generics, design-patterns

For example we have simple interface for generic repository:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T: class, IAgregateRoot
{
    void Insert(T agregateRoot);

    void Delete(T agregateRoot);

    IQueryable<T> GetAll();

    IQueryable<T> SearchFor(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);

    T GetById(Guid id);
}
```

Its necessary to implement this using JSON.NET. What is the best way to do this? Should we use some data types from .NET to store collection in memory, e.g. System.Data.Linq.Table?

Comment: Good question, but voted to close: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 1):

I enjoy the setup of this guys repository pattern. Though I feel it is getting a bit heavy now. You could take the parts you like and strip out the rest like I have done. Mainly look at the Repository implementation.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140227121645/http://blog.longle.net/2013/05/11/genericizing-the-unit-of-work-pattern-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework-in-mvc/)